# How to know when a google cloud function has finished processing?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I want to use a Google Cloud Function that triggers when an image is uploaded to a storage bucket - the functional will resize the image and generate a set of images at different sizes to render responsively.

I have a basic idea of how to set this up, but the issue I'm running into is that before the new images can be used on my site, the function has to finish processing them and uploading them to a new bucket.

Until that time I don't want to try to render the images.

Is there a simple way I can know when this processing is finished?

Comment: You will know the Function is finished (successfully) because the object will appear in the destination bucket. If you need a better response system, you must design that yourself. Your post is not specific enough to recommend a correct design.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions doesn't have anything built in to itself to notify anything of any completion.  You'll have to build something yourself, and it won't be simple.  On top of that, there are any number of solutions depending on what is the thing (presumably another software components) that needs to know when the function is complete. You'll need some sort of channel of communication to that thing.  This is well outside the scope of Cloud Functions itself.

You didn't specify what is the other component that needs to know -- this makes it impossible to prescribe a single option. Since you're on GCP, you have a number of tools available.  There is not one simple solution for all use cases.  I'll list two options.

### Cloud PubSub

As the last action in your Cloud Function, you could send a message to a pubsub topic with a payload containing whatever information about the completed task that the other software needs to know.  That other software needs to subscribe to the topic and determine per-message if the completed task was interesting to it.

This strategy probably mostly makes sense if the software component is something on your backend that can receive pubsub messages.  It could even be another Cloud Function that's triggered on a pubsub topic.

### Cloud Firestore

As the last action in your Cloud Function, you could write a document in Firestore containing whatever information about the completed task that the other software needs to know.  That other software needs to listen to the collection or document, and determine if the completed task was interesting to it.

This strategy probably mostly makes sense if it's your end-user-facing application frontend that needs the notification, since it wouldn't make sense to bake service account credentials into it for use with pubsub.

### Webhook

You could arrange for your function to trigger a webhook URL and deliver the payload that way.  This makes sense if your other component is abstracted away from your main software components on GCP.

### Firebase Cloud Messaging

If your component is a web or mobile app, an FCM message could be delivered to it with a payload.  FCM messaging is not 100% reliable.

### In any event

You'll likely want to arrange for the function and your other software component to agree ahead of time on a unique ID for the work so that it can easily filter all this data for the ones that are interesting (if using Firestore, this would be your unique document ID to listen to).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to link several operation in sequence (or even in parallel and wait for all), I recommend to have a look on [Cloud Workflow](https://cloud.google.com/workflows).

When the input file comes in, use [eventarc to trigger your workflow](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/integrating-eventarc-and-workflows), invoke your function with the new file and wait for completion.

Then, continue your processing and rendering